# Difference in padding integer and string in keras

Tags: python, keras, nlp

I'm trying to pad a text for a seq2seq model.

```
from keras_preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences

x=[["Hello, I'm Bhaskar", "This is Keras"], ["This is an", "experiment"]]
pad_sequences(sequences=x, maxlen=5, dtype='object', padding='pre', value="<PAD>")
```

I encounter following error:

```
ValueError: `dtype` object is not compatible with `value`'s type: <class 'str'>
You should set `dtype=object` for variable length strings.
```

However, when I try to do same for integer it works well.

```
x=[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
pad_sequences(sequences=x, maxlen=5, padding='pre', value=0)

Output:
array([[0, 0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 0, 4, 5, 6]], dtype=int32)
```

I hope to get output as:

```
[["<PAD>", "<PAD>", "<PAD>", "Hello, I'm Bhaskar", "This is Keras"], ["<PAD>", "<PAD>","<PAD>", "This is an", "experiment"]]
```

Comment: You can't passing strings directly. Maybe you can refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46323296/keras-pad-sequences-throwing-invalid-literal-for-int-with-base-10

Comment: For a seq2seq model, you could first tokenize the sentences and then pad those integer sequences. Seq2seq model will anyways accept String values.

Comment: I'm making a seq2seq using sentence encoding.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by the Error, change `dtype` to `object`(not string but to an object itself), It will do the job for you.

```
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences

x=[["Hello, I'm Bhaskar", "This is Keras"], ["This is an", "experiment"]]
pad_sequences(sequences=x, maxlen=5, dtype=object, padding='pre', value="<PAD>")
```

**Output**

```
array([['<PAD>', '<PAD>', '<PAD>', "Hello, I'm Bhaskar", 'This is Keras'],
       ['<PAD>', '<PAD>', '<PAD>', 'This is an', 'experiment']],
      dtype=object)
```