# keras pad_sequence for string data type

Tags: keras, nlp, sequence-to-sequence, elmo

I have a list of sentences. I want to add padding to them; but when I use keras pad_sequence like this:

```
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
s = [["this", "is", "a", "book"], ["this", "is", "not"]]
g = pad_sequences(s, dtype='str', maxlen=10, value='_PAD_')
```

the result is:

```
array([['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', 't', 'i', 'a', 'b'],
       ['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', 't', 'i', 'n']], dtype='<U1')
```

Why it is not working properly?

I want to use this result as the input to the ELMO embedding and I need string sentences not integer encoding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of  [Difference in padding integer and string in keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55220072/difference-in-padding-integer-and-string-in-keras).

Answer (score 3):

Change `dtype` to `object`, It will do the job for you.

```
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences

s = [["this", "is", "a", "book"], ["this", "is", "not"]]
g = pad_sequences(s, dtype=object, maxlen=10, value='_PAD_')
print(g)
```

**OutPut:**

```
array([['_PAD_', '_PAD_', '_PAD_', '_PAD_', '_PAD_', '_PAD_', 'this',
        'is', 'a', 'book'],
       ['_PAD_', '_PAD_', '_PAD_', '_PAD_', '_PAD_', '_PAD_', '_PAD_',
        'this', 'is', 'not']], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score -1):

The text should be first converted into numeric values. Keras provides tokenizer and two methods fit_on_texts and texts_to_sequences to work with text data.

Refer this keras documentation [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/master/keras_preprocessing/text.py)

Tokenizer : This helps in vectorizing a text corpus, by turning each
    text into either a sequence of integers (each integer being the index
    of a token in a dictionary) or into a vector where the coefficient
    for each token could be binary, based on word count

fit_on_texts: This creates vocabulary index which is based on word frequency.

texts_to_sequences: This transforms each text in texts to a sequence of integers.

```
from keras.preprocessing import text, sequence
s = ["this", "is", "a", "book", "of my choice"]
tokenizer = text.Tokenizer(num_words=100,lower=True)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(s)
seq_token = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(s)
g = sequence.pad_sequences(seq_token, maxlen=10)
g
```

Output

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 6, 7]], dtype=int32)
```